# Chart.js how to change point radius of scatter charts on resize events?

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to change the radius of the points on a scatter chart when the chart resizes. I know we can specify a `onResize` callback in `options`, but I'm not sure how to update the radius of the points. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the answer myself. You can edit the properties of chart data in `chart.config.data.datasets`.